# recharts styling with jss

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss, recharts

Hi I am trying to use material-ui with recharts in a react project.

I am trying to translate the following css into jss.

```
.recharts-wrapper .recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal line:last-child {
    stroke-opacity: 0
}
```

My attempt:

```
import createStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/createStyles";

export const styles = () =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      'recharts-wrapper': {
        'recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal': {
          'line': {
            '&:last-child': {
              'stroke-opacity': 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

this has no effect. I do see that there is an element named `recharts-cartesian-grid` between `recharts-wrapper` and `recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal` but I'm not sure it matters. My attempts to rename the classes to camel case have not been successful as strings or not as strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no effect because Recharts sets stroke opacity via style attribute which has higher priority than your style definition. To override you either need to add `!important` or set `display: none` instead of opacity.